# Is Google Maps SDK available for Apple Watch watchOS?

Tags: google-maps, watchos

I am trying to get Google Maps working on WatchOS apple watch. Is there a way i can use and display Google maps in watchOS? has Google released it for Apple Watch?

Answer (score 0):

google maps doesn't have the map view in WatchOS, it only shows directions in their watch APP. Instead you can add the Apple Maps into your WatchOS APP.